# Appending non-empty lines to itab with COND operator

Tags: abap, internal-tables

I have an internal table in which I have to move line items based on value on 3 variables using the value operator.

```
types: 
 ty_table type standard table of string with default key.

Data(Lv_var_1) = 'LINE 1'.
Data(Lv_var_2) = 'LINE 2'.
Data(Lv_var_3) = ''.

data(lt_table) = value ty_table( ( cond #( WHEN lv_var_1 is not initial THEN lv_var_1 ) )
                                 ( cond #( WHEN lv_var_2 is not initial THEN lv_var_2 ) )
                                 ( cond #( WHEN lv_var_3 is not initial THEN lv_var_3 ) ) ).
```

Here lv_var_3 is empty. For me when any variable is empty, it shouldn't even create a row in the
lt_table.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is to use [`LINES OF`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenvalue_constructor_params_lspc.htm) so that to append an arbitrary number of lines from an intermediate internal table, which can be potentially empty (0 line added) or not (any number of lines, in your case 1 line):

```
types:
 ty_table type standard table of string with default key.

Data(Lv_var_1) = `LINE 1`.
Data(Lv_var_2) = `LINE 2`.
Data(Lv_var_3) = ``.

data(lt_table) = value ty_table(
    ( LINES OF cond ty_table( WHEN lv_var_1 is not initial THEN VALUE #( ( lv_var_1 ) ) ) )
    ( LINES OF cond ty_table( WHEN lv_var_2 is not initial THEN VALUE #( ( lv_var_2 ) ) ) )
    ( LINES OF cond ty_table( WHEN lv_var_3 is not initial THEN VALUE #( ( lv_var_3 ) ) ) ) ).
```

But you may realize that the code is not legible, other codes are possible like adding all the lines then deleting the initial lines:

```
DATA(lt_table) = VALUE ty_table(
  ( lv_var_1 ) ( lv_var_2 ) ( lv_var_3 ) ).
DELETE lt_table WHERE table_line IS INITIAL.
```

Or the same principle but less legible with constructor expressions:

```
Data(lt_table) = value ty_table(
    FOR <line> IN VALUE ty_table( ( lv_var_1 ) ( lv_var_2 ) ( lv_var_3 ) )
    WHERE ( table_line IS NOT INITIAL )
    ( <line> ) ).
```

Or another possibility like the first one, but without repeating the variable names:

```
TYPES ty_vars TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF REF TO string WITH EMPTY KEY.
DATA(lt_table) = VALUE ty_table(
  FOR var IN VALUE ty_vars( ( REF #( lv_var_1 ) ) ( REF #( lv_var_2 ) ) ( REF #( lv_var_3 ) ) )
  ( LINES OF COND ty_table( WHEN var->* NE `` THEN VALUE #( ( var->* ) ) ) ) ).
```